# Setting the cameras focus in ios7 xcode. opencv

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, opencv, ios7

I am making an ios 7 app that will calibrate my iphones intrinsics and then reconstruct 3d points using 2 iphones. For this I need to lock the focus while running the opencv checkerboard calibration. Then when I go to use this intrinsic calibration for reconstructing and the detection of objects, I need to set and lock the phones focus back to the same value that was used when running the intrinsic calibration.

So how can I set the focus of my iphones camera to a given value? I have done some googling but have uncovered nothing.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but with iOS 7 you can't do this. You can lock the focus, but you can't set it to a specific point (nor can you read what the focus position is, come to that). Your focus control is restricted to locking, unlocking and setting the focus bias (near objects, far objects or full-range). And you can monitor whether the device is currently focusing or not. But that's it.

So if you're developing for iOS 7, you're out of luck; if you can use iOS 8 as your baseline, on the other hand...

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you will be using AVFoundation. There are other questions/answers out there on how to set up an AVCaptureSession. Once you have your device(s) set up, you can set the focus mode like so:

```
        AVCaptureDevice *device = [[self getActiveVideoDeviceInput] device];
        NSError *error = nil;
        if ([device lockForConfiguration:&error])
        {
            if ([device isFocusModeSupported:AVCaptureFocusModeLocked])
            {
                [device setFocusMode:AVCaptureFocusModeLocked];
            }
            [device unlockForConfiguration];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }
```

So basically, you will set your focus mode at some point, and then you can store in a property what that mode was. You can then update/change it later on per your requirements.

Also, this documentation explains more about the three possible focus modes:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html